# How to re-rendering APP.js after User Login

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router

I have a React Application. If user in not authenticated I show Login component for any path. Here is the code:

```
function App() {
    userDetails = getUserDetails();
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          { userDetails !== '' ?
          (
            <MyComponent />
          ) : (
            <Login />
          ) }
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

The problem is that, after user authentication userDetails variable is filled and user is redirected to new path (for ex: myapp/myComponent) but app.js file is not rerendered. Still Login component is shown.

Should I call something to rerender app.js or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `?`:

```
function App() {
    userDetails = getUserDetails();
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Router>
          {userDetails !== '' ? // <=== This here
            <MyComponent /> :
            <Login />
          }
        </Router>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

### EDIT #1:

You are also not using the `<Router>` component correctly. I guess(?) it's from `react-router` package, so I would suggest you specify a `<Authenticated>` route to handle the auth for routes inside the Router. You can see how to do it here: https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx in line 37 of the demo

### EDIT #2:

Here are the docs for v4/v5:https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow
line 27

Comment: Thanks, questionmark was missing only in this post, not in real code, so the problem still exists.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what it is, updating answer